# Pymongo not finding recently created element in pytest

Tags: mongodb, pytest, pymongo, fastapi

I am writing a unit test where I check if an object can be found after being inserted in a mongodb, my unit test looks like this:

```
class TestReviewCRUD:
    app = FastAPI()
    config = dotenv_values("../.env")
    app.include_router(review_router, tags=["reviews"], prefix="/review")

    def setup_method(self):
        self.app.db_client = MongoClient(f'mongodb://{self.config["DB_USER"]}:{self.config["DB_PASSWORD"]}@localhost:27017/')
        self.app.db = self.app.db_client[self.config['TEST_DB_NAME']]

    def teardown_method(self):
        self.app.db_client.close()

    def test_get_review(self):
        with TestClient(self.app) as client:
            response = self.given_a_new_review(client)
            assert response.status_code == 201 # <- this works

            new_review = client.get(f'/review/{response.json().get("_id")}')
            assert new_review.status_code == 200 # <- this doesn't work
```

The element seems to be added to the database (per the 201 http code) and if I go into the docker container, I can see it in the mongo database, but running that get keeps failing, I'm not that versed in python so maybe I am missing something? My get method is structured as:

```
@router.get("/{id}", response_description="Get a single review by id", response_model=Review)
def find_review(id: str, request: Request):
    review = request.app.db["my_db"].find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
    if review is not None:
        return review

    raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"Review with ID {id} not found")
```

If I look for an existing ID, it works, it is failing when I insert a new object and immediately look for it

Could someone shed a light, please?

Comment: What type and value does `response.json().get("_id")` have?

Comment: @rickhg12hs `None`

Comment: Would you show `response.json()`?

Comment: `{'detail': 'Review with ID 63865ede62762c8876b267ca not found'}`

Comment: So, `response = self.given_a_new_review(client)` isn't working?

Comment: I mean inserting a new record works, the problem is fetching a newly inserted record.